# How do I read/write (program) the MBR/VBR of a flash drive?

Tags: windows, bootloader, read-write, mbr

I'm looking for a method of reading/writing (actually programming) the Master Boot Record (or maybe VBR) of a usb mass storage device. Actually its a flash drive whose MBR I want to program, so that whenever I plug it into any computer, a program (stored on my flash drive in a file) gets executed.

I know quite a bit of assembly but I don't know how to go about programming MBRs..
Please help

Thanks

Comment: preferably windows..I also use backtrack..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using linux, you can simple open the device file /dev/sdXY and write to it, the MBR will be the first 512 bytes.

Comment: I'm using windows 7, anyways, if I use backtrack from virtual machine, is it still possible to do what you said?

Comment: If you're forwarding usb or use the device directly, e.g. not via a container, it should work.

Comment: I opened the device file, but I got the contents in binary..I need to see the assembly commands..So that I can edit it..How do I do that?

Comment: You're going to need a disassembler.